# Why do I get null pointer exception trying to access EditText data?

Tags: android

My application has several EditText boxes, and when the "done" button is pressed I validate the input and return the activity result.  The problem is that when I try to read the data it is null, and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
public class CreatePlayer extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private EditText textFirstName;
private EditText textLastName;
private EditText jerseyNumber;
private Spinner spinner;

private int arrayID;

private boolean validFirstName = false;
private boolean validLastName = false;
private boolean validJerseyNumber = false;
private boolean validPosition = false;

private static final String TAG = "CreatePlayer";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createplayer);

    final EditText textFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playername_first_edit);
    EditText textLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playername_last_edit);
    final EditText jerseyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playernum_edit);

    arrayID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("arrayID");
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, arrayID, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    textFirstName
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_first_name));

                        System.out.println(v.getText());
                        System.out.println(result);
                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_first_name));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.v(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.v(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validFirstName = true;
                            //textFirstName = (EditText) v.getText();
                        }

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    textLastName
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_last_name));
                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_last_name));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.v(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.v(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validLastName = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    jerseyNumber
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_jerseynum));
                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_jerseynum));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.v(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.v(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.v(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validJerseyNumber = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
}

public void okClicked(View v) {

    PlayerInfo newPlayer;

    if (validFirstName && validLastName && validJerseyNumber
            && validPosition) {
        Log.v(TAG, "JerseyNumber = " + jerseyNumber);
        // jerseyNumber is null???
        int num = Integer.parseInt(jerseyNumber.getText().toString());
        String type = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "type = " + type);
        String name = textFirstName.getText().toString() + " "
                + textLastName.getText().toString();
        newPlayer = new PlayerInfo(BaseBoard.playerIDCounter, num, type,
                name);
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(getString(R.string.players_create), newPlayer);
        setResult(5, result);
        this.finish();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Invalid input. Try something like John Smith, #27, PG",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void cancelClicked(View v) {
    this.setResult(-1, null);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    validPosition = true;
    System.out.println(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

Comment: Do you know what line of code the exception happened on?

Comment: Update on this.  If I change it to jerseyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playernum_edit); from EditText jerseyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playernum_edit); i get JerseyNumber = android.widget.EditText@405db898 but it still gives a null pointer exception.

Comment: The line that causes the exception is int num = Integer.parseInt(jerseyNumber.getText().toString());  Clearly jerseyNumber is not valid.  I am wondering if IME_ACTION_DONE is destroying the value for jerseyNumber and should I change it to IME_ACTION_NEXT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was obscuring the member.  This works:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newcreateplayer);

    textFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playername_first_edit);
    textLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playername_last_edit);
    jerseyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playernum_edit);

    arrayID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("arrayID");
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, arrayID, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    textFirstName
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                //@Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {

                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_first_name));
                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_first_name));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.d(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validFirstName = true;
                        }

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    textLastName
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                //@Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_last_name));
                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_last_name));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.d(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validLastName = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    jerseyNumber
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                //@Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile(getString(R.string.regex_jerseynum));
                        boolean result = v
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .matches(
                                        getString(R.string.regex_jerseynum));
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "pattern=" + p.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "text=" + v.getText());
                        Log.d(TAG, "result=" + result);
                        Log.d(TAG, "find=" + m.find());

                        if (result) {
                            validJerseyNumber = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Although this works on the Samsung Galaxy Tablet, it doesn't work on other devices.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `final` modifier on `textFirstName`, so you can't reassign to it.  I guess you added the `final` modifier so you could access `textFirstName` inside the `OnEditorActionListener`.  I think you'd be better off creating new `EditText` references in the `OnEditorActionListener`.